# Android Studio only: How to Create a Service-only project?

Tags: android-studio

When creating a new project in Android Studio, I am presented with **Activity-only** type of projects:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project.html#Step3AddActivity

I would like to create a Service-only project with Android Studio. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In step 3 select "Add no activity". Android studio will create an empty application. Then add your service(s).

Comment: +1 but that's a workaround, no? Isn't there a service-specific option in Android Studio? That will provide the entire skeleton of a service-only project? Just like it does for many other types of Activity type applications?

Comment: @JaySouper There is no shortcut wizard for services like activities do. What you can do is use the steps outlined in this tutorial: 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_services.htm

Comment: @VeryObjective Thanks. For lack of other answers I am accepting Okas' answer although he did not outline how to add services. At least he provided the right choice when using that wizard.